# Display the same view across multiple tabs, swiftui

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationview, tabbed-view

I have an app with a TabView. One of these tabs(1) displays a CartView.
There is another tab(2) that Adds items to the cart and Also allows Navigation to the CartView. The contents of the cart are maintained in an EnvironmentObject CartModel Object.
The issue I am having is that When I add items to Cart and navigate to the CartView, I am able to see the items. Should I back out and add something else, I can still see all the items as long as I am in tab(2). However I cannot see anything when I try to access the cart via tab(1). Hoping to get some pointers on what is happening here.
Clearly the underlying model code is accessible to the CartView on one of the tabs.

Relevant code:
Tabbed View:

```
 var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
            StoreByCategoryView()
                .tag(0)
                .tabItem { Image(systemName: "bag") }
            CreditDetailsView()
                .tag(1)
                .tabItem { Image(systemName: "creditcard") }
            CartView()
                .tag(2)
                .tabItem { Image(systemName: "cart") }
            SettingsView()
                .tag(3)
                .tabItem { Image(systemName: "gearshape") }
            SocialMainView()
                .tag(4)
                .tabItem { Image(systemName: "globe") }
            
        }
    }
    .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    .navigationBarHidden(true)
    .padding(.horizontal, 5)
}
```

CartView

```
struct CartView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var cartModel: CartModel
    
    var body: some View {
        let _ = print("CartView")
        if cartModel.totalQuantity == 0 {
            Text("Nothing present in the cart")
        } else {
            let _ = print("CartView --- ELSE")
            VStack(alignment:.leading , spacing: 5){
                let _ = print("CartView --- VSATCK")
                List {
                    ScrollView(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.vertical/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, showsIndicators: false){
                        ForEach(Array(cartModel.productQuantityMap.keys), id: \.self) {(product) in
                            CartItemView(product: product)
                        }
                    }
                }
                Group {
                    Divider()
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        Text("Total: $A\(cartModel.totalValue)"  as String)
                            .fontWeight(.semibold)
                            .foregroundColor(.primary)
                    }
                    .padding(.bottom)
                    Divider()
                }
                
                HStack(alignment: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.center/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, spacing: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/nil/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/){
                    Spacer()
                    Button(action: {
                        checkoutModel.checkout(productQty: cartModel.productQuantityMap, customertoken: session.customerAccessToken)
                    }){
                        Text("Checkout")
                            .font(.system(.title2, design: .rounded))
                            .fontWeight(.semibold)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                        
                    }
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 35)
                    .padding(15)
                    .background(Color(UIColor(red: 0.39, green: 1.00, blue: 0.85, alpha: 1.00)))
                    .clipShape(Capsule())
                    Spacer()
                }
                
            }
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you inject `.environmentObject` with `CartModel`? It just sounds as you use different instances of `CartModel` in those tabs.

Comment: Thanks! I am injecting at the App level.(@main), its referenced in a couple of places, but instantiated  in the @main

Comment: Ok, then needed minimal reproducible example or access to project - provided code is not enough to find out what's going on.